# How do we prove that $x \mapsto P_x$ is universaly measurable

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

In reading Yamada and Watanabe (On the uniqueness of solutions of stochastic differential equations) in page 9 one finds:

[image]

In this statement, I can't figure out if the property $x \mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable is an hypothesis or something to be proved.

the proof of proposition 2 is as follows:

[image]

[image]
 As the author says no word on the subject, I took that it is an assumption.

Turns out  that in the sequel the authors  use proposition 2 to conclude that $x \mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable. in corollary 2

It's in page 10
[image]

I don't understand how it is proved that $P(\cdot \in B \mid \mathcal{F}_0) = P_{x_0}(B)$ is universally measurable.

The authors say they are just invoking proposition 2, But in fact universe measurability was not discussed in this proposition, and markiv property that is used afterwards depends on that.

Is the argument circular?

I believe I am missing something here.

Comment: Looks like an assumption to me. The part "if $P_x$ is the probability law of $x_t$ in $(W,\mathbb{B}(W))$ which is unique by first assumption, then $x\mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable for all $B\in\mathbb{B}(W)$" looks like defining notation. Also, note that, to prove $x\mapsto P(X)$ is universally measurable, the authors use the "proof" of proposition 2, rather than the proposition itself. To clarify your question you should post it too.

Comment: @NateRiver, thank you for your comments, could you explain what do you mean by the authors the "proof" of proposition 2?

Comment: I mean that the authors use an argument used in the proof of proposition 2, rather than the statement of this proposition, to conclude $x\mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable. I wrote proof between "" to emphasize the word proof, though perhaps I should have wrote it in italic instead.

Comment: So you also feel there is something missing inn the proof (or rather "proof")?

Comment: Yes, now that I look at the proof of proposition #2, the proof of corollary #2 looks suspicious. Then again, in proposition #2 they show that if $x\mapsto P_x(B)$ is unversally measurable, then, for any stopping time $\sigma$, $P_{x_{\sigma}}(B)=P(x_{\cdot}\in B|F_{\sigma})$. In corollary #2 they only claim that for the particular stopping time $\sigma=0$, we have $P_{x_0}(B)=P(x_{\cdot}\in B|F_0)$. Perhaps to prove this it isn't necessary to assume $x\mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable.

Comment: Thanks @NateRiver, for your genuine interest on the question. It seems to me that if we do need to assume  that $x\mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable then we don't need to assume that $x\mapsto P_x(B)$ is universally measurable at all. Maybe that is the case, if $P$ is a solution then $P \mid \mathcal{F}_0$ is also a solution  and in presence of unicity yelds that $x \mapsto P_x$ is universally measurable. I don't know....